# Scrolling link text on hover - endless marquee effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, marquee

I'm looking for a performant and also smooth solution for links that scroll their text inside of their inline-block box like a marquee effect.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    
    function scroll(ele){
     var s = $(ele).text().substr(1)+$(ele).text().substr(0,1);
     $(ele).text(s);
    }

    scrollInterval = null;
    function startScrolling(e) {
        if (!scrollInterval) {
            scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
                scroll(e)
            },100);
        }
    }

    function stopScrolling(e) {
        clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        scrollInterval = null;
    }

    $(".mali").hover(function(){
        startScrolling($(this));
    });

    $(".mali").mouseout(function(){
        stopScrolling($(this));
    });

    $(".mali").mousedown(function(){
        stopScrolling($(this));
    });

  });
```

```css
.mali {
        display: inline-block;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;  
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Something <a href="#" class="mali">something&nbsp;darkside</a>, Something something complete.
```

My solution so far is something I actually found here on stackoverlow in another thread and tried to work with it.

Two problems though.

1.) As this is basically using an interval to loop through the single letters this effect is not very smooth. The effect is stuttering.

Has anyone an Idea on how to make this more smooth? Maybe in that case don't use this method at all and maybe use a CSS transition to animate the text?

2.) Does anyone have a clever solution on how to return to the initial state once I hover off? I want the effect on hover but when moving the mouse off the link it should animate back to the initial text state.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) You can save initial state and then just revert it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    function scroll(ele){
     var s = $(ele).text().substr(1)+$(ele).text().substr(0,1);
     $(ele).text(s);
    }

    scrollInterval = null;
    function startScrolling(e) {
        if (!scrollInterval) {
            $(e).data("text", $(e).text());
            scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
                scroll(e)
            },100);
        }
    }

    function stopScrolling(e) {
        clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        scrollInterval = null;
        $(e).text($(e).data("text"));
    }

    $(".mali").hover(function(){
        startScrolling($(this));
    });

    $(".mali").mouseout(function(){
        stopScrolling($(this));
    });

    $(".mali").mousedown(function(){
        stopScrolling($(this));
    });

  });
```

```css
.mali {
        display: inline-block;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;  
        transition: all .2s;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Something <a href="#" class="mali">something&nbsp;darkside</a>, Something something complete.
```

1) As a smooth animation, i thought of this as a PoC. Maybe it will help you with further ideas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Those global data could be stored in element's data.
    var indent = 0,
        width = 0,
        padding = 10;
    function scroll(ele){
      // Every iteration decrease indent by value
      indent -= 1;
      
      // If is indent greater than or equal than real width
      // (width with padding) reset indent.
      if(-indent >= width+padding)
        indent = 0;
       
       // Aplly property
      $(ele).css("text-indent", indent);
    }

    var scrollInterval = null;
    function startScrolling(e) {
        if (!scrollInterval) {
            // Get text and real width
            let text = $(e).text();
            width = $(e).width()
          
            $(e)
              // Set real width & height, so that container stays
              .width($(e).width())
              .height($(e).height())
              
              // Save text to data for reset
              .data("text", text)
              
              // Add 2 spans with text:
              // <span>text</span><span>text</span>
              // Where second span has defined padding on the left
              .html($("<span>").text(text))
              .append($("<span>").text(text).css("padding-left", padding+"px"));
             
           resumeScrolling(e);
        }
    }

    function stopScrolling(e) {
        pauseScrolling(e);
        
        // Reset
        $(e)
          // Revert real text and reset indent
          .text($(e).data("text"))
          .css("text-indent", indent = 0);
    }

    function pauseScrolling(e) {
        clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        scrollInterval = null;
    }

    function resumeScrolling(e) {
        if (!scrollInterval) {
          // Every 30ms repeat animation. It must be at least 25x per second
          // so it runs smoothly. (So 1 - 40).
          scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
            scroll(e)
          },30);
       }
    }

    $(".mali").hover(function(){
        startScrolling($(this));
    });

    $(".mali").mouseout(function(){
        stopScrolling($(this));
    });

    $(".mali").mousedown(function(){
        stopScrolling($(this));
    });

    $("#start").click(function(){
      startScrolling($(".mali"));
    });
    $("#stop").click(function(){
      stopScrolling($(".mali"));
    });
    $("#pause").click(function(){
      pauseScrolling($(".mali"));
    });
    $("#resume").click(function(){
      resumeScrolling($(".mali"));
    });

  });
```

```css
.mali {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  /*
  This could help, but you can't reset text-indent without animation.
  transition: all .1s;
  */
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* When you hover element, new span elements
can't take pointer events, so your elements
stays hovered. */
.mali span {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Something <a href="#" class="mali">something&nbsp;darkside</a>, Something something complete.

<br><br>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="resume">Resume</button>
```

Idea behind this is:

- make element `overflow:hidden;` so no text will overflow
- set fix dimension
- duplicate text inside
- change text indent every x miliseconds (x < 40 so it is smooth, must be at least 25fps)
- when it overflows, reset it so it can be in infinite loop

Comment: … thank you very much. Can you give me some sort of small description on what you're doing in option 2? If I stay over the link longer with the mouse it resets it self shortly.

Comment: I explained and added smooth reset, including padding.

Comment: thank you for your great support! Awesome. Regarding "set fix dimension" … what  do you mean here? I would want this to work "out of the box" on all links with a certain class where I don't have to set a fix width. Also, one more thing. How would I reset it?

And last question, if I wanted it to be in line with the other text would I simply use paddings or margins (or relative position) to move it in line again? As overflow hidden breaks the baseline of course.

Comment: Because there is text duplicated, and will overflow you need to fix container using absolute dimensions. But there will be taken real objects dimensions, so it's not hardcoded. But yes, padding is yet fix, it must be refactored. Reset, just calling `stopScrolling` will reset it. So revert text (from data) and eventually remove fix dimensions (set width & height to auto). `vertical-align: middle;` would help you center it again.

Comment: @M1KO I'm not capable to do the stopScrolling reset myself. Would you be able to help me out here one last time. Thanks in advance. Vertical align works just fine, thanks.

Comment: @matt Not sure what you mean, i added some control buttons to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I mean I'm not able to make the animation so, that it's endless. right now if I stay over the text for too long it resets itself and "jumps back". I want the marquee effect to run forever without any hiccups and when leaving the mouse revert to its original state.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. What browser do you use. I tried it in Chrome and it works as expected.

Comment: it works in the demo above, but check here: https://jsfiddle.net/8saozLt7/ … i just copied everything out from stackoverflow. Happens in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: How would I increase the speed for the animation? It's funny that it's slower in Safari as in Chrome for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210249/discussion-between-m1k1o-and-matt).